# How to obtain stock market company sector from ticker or company name in python

Tags: python, xpath, stock, sector

Given a company *ticker* or name I would like to get its *sector* using python.

I have tried already several potential solutions but none has worked succesfully

The two most promising are:

1) Using the script from: https://gist.github.com/pratapvardhan/9b57634d57f21cf3874c

```
from urllib import urlopen
from lxml.html import parse

'''
Returns a tuple (Sector, Indistry)
Usage: GFinSectorIndustry('IBM')
'''
def GFinSectorIndustry(name):
  tree = parse(urlopen('http://www.google.com/finance?&q='+name))
  return tree.xpath("//a[@id='sector']")[0].text, tree.xpath("//a[@id='sector']")[0].getnext().text
```

However I am using `python --version 3.8`

I have been able to tweak this solution, but the last line is not working and I am completely new to scraping web pages, so I would appreciate if anyone has some suggestions.

Here is my current code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from lxml.html import parse

name="IBM"
req = Request('http://www.google.com/finance?&q='+name, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req)

tree = parse(webpage)
```

But then the last part is not working and I am very new to this `xpath` syntax:

```
tree.xpath("//a[@id='sector']")[0].text, tree.xpath("//a[@id='sector']")[0].getnext().text
```

2) The other option was embedding `R`'s `TTN` package as shown here: [Find which sector a stock belongs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432512/find-which-sector-a-stock-belongs-to)

However, I want to run it within my Jupyter notebook, and it is just taking ages to run `ss <- stockSymbols()`

Comment: There is no `a` tag whose `id` is *sector* on, say, [www.google.com/search?q=MSFT](https://www.google.com/search?q=MSFT). Do you have a concret example of what you really want to get ? If so, enrich your question with such precision.

Comment: @keepAlive, for example from here: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ibm 

I want to get the *sector*, which is: *Business/Consumer Services*.

This is shown on the left of the graph, below the stock prize.

Answer (score 1):

*Following your comment*, for [marketwatch.com/investing/stock](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ibm) ***specifically***, the xpath that is likely to work is `"//div[@class='intraday__sector']/span[@class='label']"` meaning that doing

```
tree.xpath("//div[@class='intraday__sector']/span[@class='label']")[0].text
```

should return the desired information.

> I am completely new to scraping web pages [...]

Some precisions:

1. This xpath totally depends on the website you are looking at, explaining why there were no hope in searching `"//a[@id='sector']"` in the page you mention in comments, since this xpath (now outdated) was google-finance specific. Put differently, you first need to "study" the page you are interested in to know where the information you want is located.
2. To conduct such "study" I use [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) and check any xpath in the console, doing `$x(<your-xpath-of-interest>)` where the function `$x` is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities?hl=en#xpath) (with examples!).
3. Luckily for you, the information you want to get from [marketwatch.com/investing/stock](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ibm) -- the sector's name -- is statically generated <sub>(i.e. not dynamically generated at page loading, in which case other scraping techniques would have been required, resorting to other python libraries such as [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).. but this is another question).</sub>

Comment: This `tree.xpath("//div[@class='intraday__sector']/span[@class='label']")` gives an empty `list`. From the `tree` variable generated with the code of the question using the google website.

Comment: @alejandro A xpath that works for a given website, won't work for another website. This one works for [marketwatch.com/investing/stock](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ibm). See update.

Comment: yeah I figured, but when I tried to do it for that website I get the following error: `HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed`. Which seems to be related to the `urlopen` part of the code.

Comment: @al note that 405 error is independant from the core subject of your post. That being said, have you seen [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47951270/4194079) ?

Comment: I was indeed looking at it ;) OK, I will keep troubleshooting then! Thanks, for your nice response so far, once I am done with this I'll accept if all works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily obtain the sector for any given company/ticker with yahoo finance:

```
import yfinance as yf

tickerdata = yf.Ticker('TSLA') #the tickersymbol for Tesla
print (tickerdata.info['sector'])
```

Code returns: 'Consumer Cyclical'

If you want other information about the company/ticker, just print(tickerdata.info) to see all other possible dictionary keys and corresponding values, like ['sector'] used in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:

*How to obtain stock market company sector from ticker or company name in python?*

I had to find a work around after reading some material and some nice suggestions from @keepAlive.

The following does the job in a reverse way, i.e. gets the companies given the sector. There are 10 sectors, so it is not too much work if one wants info for all sectors: https://www.stockmonitor.com/sectors/

Given that marketwatch.com/investing/stock was throwing a 405 Error, I decided to use https://www.stockmonitor.com/sectors/, for example:

https://www.stockmonitor.com/sector/healthcare/

Here is the code:

```
import requests

import pandas as pd

from lxml.html import parse
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

headers = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3)" + " "
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)" + " " + "Chrome/35.0.1916.47" +
    " " + "Safari/537.36"
]

url = 'https://www.stockmonitor.com/sector/healthcare/'

headers_dict = {'User-Agent': headers[0]}
req = Request(url, headers=headers_dict)
webpage = urlopen(req)

tree = parse(webpage)
```

```
healthcare_tickers = []
for element in tree.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[@class='text-left']/a"):

    healthcare_tickers.append(element.text)

pd.Series(healthcare_tickers)
```

Thus, `healthcare_tickers` has the stock companies in the *healthcare sector*.